# Array dimension problems for program that creates map of yearly max rainfall

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, dimension

I am trying to create a map of yearly max rainfall for a given set of years.

I have ten NC files and each file is of 3-hr rainfall and contains 5 years worth of data. For the rainfall data I am using, it is in a 3D array: `pr(time,lat,lon)` with dimensions `(14616, 145, 192)`

I need to find the max rainfall for each year with Matplotlib, create a world map of this data. I am not sure of the best way to go about doing this considering there are 5 years per NetCDF file, meaning I would need to find 5 maximum values out of 14616 data points per file with 10 total files.

My first thought was to section of the file by year as so (starting with just one file for now):

```
a = pr[0:2928]
b = pr[2929:5849]
c = pr[5850:8769]
d = pr[8770:11689]
e = pr[11690:14617]
```

Then calculate the max value for each one, using `np.max`, and make a new array with these values, using `np.arry`. The problem is this then results in a 1D array, and I run into a problem because my input must be a 2D array. (Otherwise it results in the error: `TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.`)

I've tried to reshape the array, with `np.reshape` (reshaped to be `(2L, 5L)`) and I am able to do that successfully, but then get the following error when trying to create the figure: `TypeError: Length of x must be number of columns in z.`

I believe that's because the lat and lon data is not included in the new array I created, but I am not completely sure on this.

I was wondering if there would be a better way to find the max values then separating it the way I did considering it's a lot of data to sort through and I'm not sure of a more efficient way to do it.

If not, I would like to know how I would be able to format my new array so it can be used to create the map. Below I also have the code to create the figure that resulted in `TypeError: Length of x must be number of columns in z.`

`yrmax1` is the new reshaped array of maximum rainfall with shape `(2L, 5L)`.

```
plt.figure(1,figsize=(10, 8))

map = Basemap(projection='cyl',\
            llcrnrlat=LLlat,urcrnrlat=URlat,\
            llcrnrlon=LLlon,urcrnrlon=URlon,\
            rsphere=6371200.,resolution='i')
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5) 
lons,lats = map(lon,lat)
cs = plt.contourf(lons,lats,yrmax1,np.linspace(-2,1,30),cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu_r, extend='both')  
plt.colorbar(cs,orientation='horizontal')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you write it all into 1 table?  It doesn't sound like that much data.

Comment: That's a fair point I could probably do that as well. It just adds some extra work and I was hoping for an easier way to do it because I'll have to do this multiple times with multiple different models.

Comment: If you have to do it multiple times, you are better off writing code to do the whole thing. As you are learning to code you will only gain a little time, but you gain a great deal in consistency.

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how to go about doing that?